# JAVA_HOME issue. JDK Seemed to not be installed correctly

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to get Android Studio installed on Cent OS 6.5. I have downloaded and unzipped the package to /usr/share/applications/Android-studio/.

I have installed jdk 8 in /usr/share/applications/ (as I understand you just unpack it there, no need to compile or execute anything...?)

I have appended /etc/profile with "JAVA_HOME=/usr/share/applications/jdk1.8.0_1118"

When I execute the studio.sh file the app begins to run (I see some Java messages in the shell) then I get the error:

"JDK Required: 'tools.jar' seems to be not in Studio classpath.
Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE".

I think this means something is wrong with my JDK files but I don't know what. I have followed multiple tutorials online about how to fix this error including the guides on [Android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html) and [Oracle's](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/) websites and as far as I can tell I've done everything correctly, but I am still getting this error. What am I missing?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure about Android, but for Windows, if using a JDK for JAVA_HOME, you're supposed to set it to the JRE included with it, not the JDK or its bin. So, maybe this would work? `JAVA_HOME=/usr/share/applications/jdk1.8.0_1118/jre`

Comment: Thanks, @kayleeFrye_onDeck. I tried that. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Darn! Sorry to hear, but I'm glad to see you got it working! Don't forget to mark your answer as the accepted answer once 48 hours have passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through some answers to similar questions (that didn't receive any votes so I had overlooked them previously) I solved the issue. I had to copy the 'tools.jar' file from /usr/share/applications/jdk1.8.0_1118/lib to /usr/share/applications/android-studio/lib. That did it. It is up and running. Apparently this file is missing from the package downloaded from the android studio website. I hope they fix that soon and save future users hassle.